# datetime parsing from excel sheet in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datetime

i want to get a datetime value from excel sheet and take the highest and the lowest date

i read the excel sheet and put it in datatable :
i tried this code :

```
protected void CheckTheFP(DataTable data)
    {
        if (data.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            DateTime ds = new DateTime();

            err.Text = DateTime.TryParseExact(data.Rows[0][2].ToString(), "MM/dd/yy hh:mm tt",
               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
               System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
               out ds) + "" ;

        }
    }
```

but i always get false ... don't know why ?

and is there a way to sort this datatable or take the highest and lowest date

[image]

this the excel sheet i read from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This format string should work:  `"M/dd/yy h:mm tt"`. I've used single M because the month has one digit, the same applies to the hours. I've used `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to prevent that all `/` will be replaced with your actual date-separator (in case that it's different).

You can use LINQ:

```
var allDateTimes = data.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => DateTime.ParseExact(row.Field<string>("Time"), "M/dd/yy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
DateTime min = allDateTimes.Min();
DateTime max = allDateTimes.Max();
```

If you want to be on the safe side you should use `TryParseExact`, for example with this code:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> allDateTimes = data.AsEnumerable()
  .Select(row => {
     string time = row.Field<string>("Time").Trim();
     DateTime dt;
     if (DateTime.TryParseExact(time, "M/dd/yy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
        return (DateTime?) dt;
     return null;  // set a breakpoint here to see which value could not be parsed
  })
  .Where(dt => dt.HasValue)
  .Select(dt => dt.Value);
DateTime min = allDateTimes.Min();
DateTime max = allDateTimes.Max();
```

**Edit**: you: *"when i try to use it on the date 11/2/14 4:42 PM you see the 11 is not in M datetime format*

The month is not the problem. Use single `d` instead because the days can have a single digit also.

So: `"M/d/yy h:mm tt"`

Comment: i got this error : 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

at the second line

Comment: @SamySammour: i have tested it with your sample strings in a DataTable and it works. Are there other strings, maybe an empty string? Then you should use `TryParseExact`.

Comment: i try it too but always give my false ... and when I user DateTime.Parse it gave me that error : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

and no empty value and all the value came from =NOW() from excel

Comment: @SamySammour: you can always set a breakpoint in my code above at `return null`. Then you see the value that cannot be parsed. Perhaps you need to use `Trim`: `string time = row.Field<string>("Time").Trim();` if there's a white-space at the beginning or end which you don't see.

Comment: its worked now ... i guess the problem was in Trim as u said 
thank you

Comment: I got another problem now ... when i try to use it on the date 11/2/14 4:42 PM
you see the 11 is not in M datetime format

Comment: @SamySammour: the month is not the problem but the day which needs to be `d` instad of `dd`. I've edited my answer again to take that into account.

Comment: it worked but when there is an error value in max and mine ... when i user 11/2/14 4:42 PM didn't take it as  the bigger value

Comment: thats what give me :min: 22/07/2014 16:51:00
 max : 12/08/2014 16:51:00 and that wrong because 11/2/14 4:42 PM is the highest value

Comment: @SamySammour: have you used the new format string `"M/d/yy h:mm tt"` as commented and shown in my answer? I ask because it works for me with your string. Of course, if a date can not be parsed it won't be used in `Min` or `Max`, that is intended.

Comment: What problem? `DateTime.ParseExact("11/2/14 4:42 PM", "M/d/yy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` will always and in every country succeed.

Comment: @SamySammour: don't you read my comments and edits? That was the third comment regarding it and the answer also mentioned it. However, I'm glad that it works now.

Comment: i am sorry but i am a little confused now because i had to deliver the project within next 5 hours and its still need some work